# Spring security authorization based on ROLES not working

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

In a Spring boot / spring security / Angular JS application..

I am trying to allow the below pages only if the user has a specified role.

```
.antMatchers("/1_reportingEntities/*.html").hasAnyRole(roles)
```

But it allow the page even if that role is not set for the user.
What am I missing ?

**Java Code**

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        String roles [] = new String[] {"ROLE_EDITOR", "ROLE_AUTHORISER" };

        http.httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()

                // Permit these resources
                .antMatchers("/login", "/4_security/login.html", "/bower_components/**", "/0_common/*.html", "/1_reportingEntities/*.js",
                        "/2_dataCollections/*.js", "/3_calendar/*.js", "/4_security/*.js", "/")
                .permitAll()
                // All other requests needs authentication
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                // Allow only if has certain roles  
                .antMatchers("/1_reportingEntities/*.html").hasAnyRole(roles)

                .and()
                // CSRF protection
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

        // Enable https
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();

    }
```

Comment: i think spring add automatically the ROLE_ for roles, try with the array {"EDITOR", "AUTHORISER"}

Comment: Either you prefix it or not with ROLE it doesnt matter, Spring can detect that.

Comment: How about try to put antMatchers.hasAnyRole before anyRequest.authenticated, check if it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose problem is with Spring. You need to change hasAnyRole() for hasAnyAuthority().

Comment: Many thanks that worked. Any idea how to show a error message / page if validation failed coz of the user not having valid roles ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring will automatically add the prefix `ROLE_` when checking with `hasAnyRole`, whereas `hasAnyAuthority` will not.

So, in your example when you use `hasAnyRole({"ROLE_EDITOR", "ROLE_AUTHORISER" })` , Spring will actually check if your user has either of the roles `{"ROLE_ROLE_EDITOR", "ROLE_ROLE_AUTHORISER" }`.

You can either use `hasAnyRole({"EDITOR", "AUTHORISER"})`, which will check if your user has been granted `{"ROLE_EDITOR", "ROLE_AUTHORISER"}`, or you can keep specifying `{"ROLE_EDITOR", "ROLE_AUTHORISER" }` but use `hasAnyAuthority.`